# Adding new python libraries to Edx Studio

Tags: python, django, edx, openedx

I'm working with OpenEdx and i want add new libraries for make new funtionalities.

I have the normal `DevStack Edx` environment (work in `Docker`).

I want add `google-api-python-client` for my project, so i added this package to:
[image]

After rebuild the image and run the container i review this packages in respective containers:[image]

Where are my libraries? 
It only happen in `Studio`, in `LMS` all is well.

So:
- Which is the correct external python packages installation's way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the original image haven't all packages installed, and after to run the `LMS` commands in a copy of the original image the new image is different from the other image: in `CMS` copy we have a initial image without other change, because doesn't exist other change.

So, for install the new requirements we created a new file for it where we apply  the commands for install and migrate packages:

```
set -e
set -o pipefail
set -x

# Bring Studio online
docker-compose $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILES up -d studio

docker-compose exec studio bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && NO_PYTHON_UNINSTALL=1 paver install_prereqs'

#Installing prereqs crashes the process
docker-compose restart studio

# Run edxapp migrations first since they are needed for the service users and OAuth clients
docker-compose exec studio bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && NO_PREREQ_INSTALL=1 paver update_db --settings devstack_docker'

docker-compose exec studio bash -c 'source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env && cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform && paver update_assets --settings devstack_docker'
```

It's all.